# What is the difference between these code snippets?

Tags: c

I have the following code snippet running great:

```
char* head = str;
char* tail = head;
while ( *tail ) {
    ++tail;
}
```

I changed the while loop for simplification and the new code is

```
char* head = str;
char* tail = head;
while ( *tail++ );
```

I believe the above 2 code snippets work same. But the 2nd one does! In GDB I see that, for a string with 32 characters, pointer tail is 33 larger than head which should be 31.

I am really baffled.

Comment: Though the **values** of the expressions (`*tail` and `*tail++`) are the same, their **side-effects** are different.

Answer (score 6):

For the second piece of code, the post-increment occurs whether or not *tail evaluates to zero.

Comment: Thanks. I have been programming C for years, but once in a while, fall the crack like this.

Answer (score 2):

Why baffled?

The increment is conditional in the first case and unconditional in the second.

The second form is probably less useful (because you have to decrement to get back to the terminator), but should be OK as you are allowed to compute (but not dereference) addresses one past the end of a allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will check if `*tail` is not 0, and if it is not 0, increment `tail`. If it is 0, it will stop the loop before incrementing `tail`.

The second one will increment `tail` then check if the old value of `tail` points to `0`. If not, it will continue. If so, it will stop, but notice that it has already incremented `tail`.

So basically the difference is the first one will leave `tail` pointing to a `0`, while the second will leave `tail` pointing to the character after the `0`.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one you need to provide a condition that you want it to apply, otherwise you'll get those side effects.

Maybe throw in a do at the end?